# Validate URL with or without protocol

Tags: php, regex

Hi I would like to validate this following urls, so they all would pass with or without http/www part in them as long as there is TLD present like .com, .net, .org etc..

Valid URLs Should Be:

```
http://www.domain.com
http://domain.com
https://www.domain.com
https://domain.com
www.domain.com
domain.com
```

To support long tlds:

```
http://www.domain.com.uk
http://domain.com.uk
https://www.domain.com.uk
https://domain.com.uk
www.domain.com.uk
domain.com.uk
```

To support dashes (-):

```
http://www.domain-here.com
http://domain-here.com
https://www.domain-here.com
https://domain-here.com
www.domain-here.com
domain-here.com
```

Also to support numbers in domains:

```
http://www.domain1-test-here.com
http://domain1-test-here.com
https://www.domain1-test-here.com
https://domain1-test-here.com
www.domain1-test-here.com
domain-here.com
```

Also maybe allow even IPs:

```
127.127.127.127
```

(but this is extra!)

Also allow dashes (-), forgot to mantion that =)

I've found many functions that validate one or another but not both at same time. 
If any one knows good regex for it, please share. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Amadan, well regex part :) Not sure how to write one to handel all of those domains.

Comment: [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate)?

Comment: @Charles, this only allows http:// and www if you don't type those in, it will not pass.

Comment: @Tux, the documentation disagrees, unless you've *tested* it.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL will fail if you do not provide the protocol, does not support internationalized domains (only ASCII) and other protocols like mailto, ssh, etc.

Answer (score 6):

For url validation perfect solution.

Above Answer is right but not work on all domains like .me, .it, .in

so please user below for url match:

```
$pattern = '/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:[a-zA-Z])|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/';

if(preg_match($pattern, "http://website.in"))
{
echo "valid";
}else{
echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: pass multiple dots

Answer (score 1):

When you ignore the path part and look for the domain part only, a simple rule would be

```
(?:https?://)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:com|net|org|gov|edu|mil)|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

If you want to support country TLDs as well you must either supply a complete (current) list or append `|..` to the TLD part.

With `preg_match` you must wrap it between some delimiters

```
$pattern = ';(?:https?://)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:com|net|org|gov|edu|mil)|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+);';
$index = preg_match($pattern, $url);
```

Usually, you use `/`. But in this case, slashes are part of the pattern, so I have chosen some other delimiter. Otherwise I must escape the slashes with `\`

```
$pattern = '/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:com|net|org|gov|edu|mil)|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/';
```

Comment: I tried this rule with preg_match and its trowing some errors. Am I missing something ? I did preg_match($pattern, $url) and your regex inside of quotes.

Comment: @Tux Please see the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular expression.  Not every problem that involves strings needs to use regexes.

Don't write your own URL validator.  URL validation is a solved problem, and there is existing code that has already been written, debugged and testing.  In fact, it comes standard with PHP.

Look at PHP's built-in filtering functionality: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Comment: Not entirely correct. URL validator (filter_var) fails miserably in PHP and yet, we do not have a good solved problem for this. The OP's rule says "as long as the TLD is present", so regex is acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) for [`filter_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

For `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` there is several flags available:

- `FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED` Requires the URL to contain a scheme
  part.
- `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` Requires the URL to contain a host
  part.
- `FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED` Requires the URL to contain a path
  part.
- `FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED` Requires the URL to contain a query
  string.

`FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED` and `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` used by default.

Lets say you want to check for path part and do not want to check for scheme part, you can do something like this (falg is a bitmask):

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, ~FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Trying to remove the scheme flag in this way doesn't work.