# Regular expression to validate url with www but optional http or https

Tags: regex

I want to have a regex that will validate url in following way

```
http://www.google.com   ->valid url
www.google.com          ->valid url
google.com              ->in-valid url
http://google.com       ->in-valid url
```

I have tried following regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735100)

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+?\.(?:[a-zA-Z])|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/
```

but it doens't validate the existence of `www`

Comment: What regex flavor/language are you using?

Comment: I am using regexp/php as validating with preg_match

Comment: Wait, what? You want to enforce that the domain starts with `www.`, but you include bits in your regex that allow for IPv4 addresses in the form `http://0.0.0.0/`? Did you just dump someone else's regex in your question in an attempt to make it look like you make some effort?

Comment: @hvd I didn't say I have made that. Did I say that? I said I  have tried. Seriously negative vote?

Comment: You certainly implied it. If it's someone else's regex, include a mention of the author in your question. See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @hvd updated my question. Now remove your negative vote

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
$re = '~\b(?:https?://)?(www\.[^.\s]+\.[^/\s]+|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)~';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY6vS1/3)

This regex will enforce `www.` after optional `htpp://` or `https://` before it.

**Another option** in PHP is to use `parse_url` function and check for `result['host']` array entry.

Answer (score 0):

To match `www` you will have to use regex like this.

**Regex:** `(?:https?:\/\/)?www\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]+|(?:\d\.?){4}`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW5pZ0/5)

Comment: How about URLs with "_"?

Comment: Are you sure about the `.`? Should be `\.`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try this as input: `www.test9/com` That should demonstrate the mistake I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Put `www` in your regex:

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www(\.[\w-]+)+|\d+(\.\d+){3})/
```

I also improved it a bit (so it doesn't match "www......" etc)

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/YTHy6WM89k).

Comment: Shouldn't IP address be matched only till `255.255.255.255` ?

Comment: @noob sure, but that's not what op is asking about. Fixing the ip range would overly complicate the answer.